# Kendo grid view row high lighting

Tags: javascript, gridview, kendo-ui, row, highlight

I am using kendo grid view with one dropdown list column. Need to highlight the row once user select any value in the dropdown list.

Comment: What have you done so far? Got an example code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a css class to the `tr`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/local-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1109/styles/kendo.default-main.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1109/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1109/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
      tr.highlight {
        background-color: #f55;
      }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="../content/shared/js/products.js"></script>

<div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: products,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                ProductName: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                UnitPrice: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                UnitsInStock: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                Discontinued: { type: "boolean", editable: true }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 20
                },
                height: 550,
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                editable: true,
                pageable: {
                    input: true,
                    numeric: false
                },
                columns: [
                    "ProductName",
                    { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                    { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                    { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px", editor: ($cell, e) => 
                     {
                       $('<select>' + 
                            '<option' + (e.model.Discontinued ? ' selected="selected"' : '') + '>True</option>' + 
                            '<option' + (!e.model.Discontinued ? ' selected="selected"' : '') + '>False</option></select>')
                         .appendTo($cell)
                         .on('change', function (dataItem, $cell, e) {
                             dataItem.Discontinued = ($(e.target).val() === 'True');
                         
                           // Highlight code
                           $cell.closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
                         }.bind(null, e.model, $cell));
                     }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EKapiFOd)